# Using variables from the array output PHP (by it's order)

Tags: php

This code outputs something like the bellow description and I need to convert each output to a PHP var's on the exact order

**eg**:

**[product-link]**

```
[0] »» $var_prod_link_0 = 'the link 0 here'; 
[1] »» $var_prod_link_1 = 'the link 1 here'; 
etc..
```

**[product-img-src]**

```
[0] »» $var_prod_img_0 = 'the image 0 link here'; 
[1] »» $var_prod_img_1 = 'the image 1 link here';
etc..
```

**[h3-title-text]**

```
[0] »» $var_title_text_0 = 'the title 0 here'; 
[1] »» $var_title_text_1 = 'the title 1 here';
etc..
```

**[price]**

```
[0] »» $var_price_0 = 'the price 0 here';
[1] »» $var_price_1 = 'the price 1 here'; 
ect..
```

**This is the code**:

```
# set the libxml parameters and create new DOMDocument/XPath objects.
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

# some basic XPath expressions
$exprs=(object)array(
    'product-link'      =>  '//a[@class="product-image-link"]',
    'product-img-src'   =>  '//a[@class="product-image-link"]/img',
    'h3-title-text'     =>  '//h3[@class="wd-entities-title"]',
    'price'             =>  '//span[@class="price"]/span/bdi'
);
# find the keys (for convenience) to be used below
$keys=array_keys( get_object_vars( $exprs ) );

# store results here
$res=array();

# loop through all patterns and issue XPath query.
foreach( $exprs as $key => $expr ){
    # add key to output and set as an array.
    $res[ $key ]=[];
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    
    # find the data if the query succeeds
    if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            switch( $key ){
                case $keys[0]:$res[$key][]=$node->getAttribute('href');break;
                case $keys[1]:$res[$key][]=$node->getAttribute('src');break;
                case $keys[2]:$res[$key][]=trim($node->textContent);break;
                case $keys[3]:$res[$key][]=trim($node->textContent);break;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res,true));
```

**The output from the above code**:

```
Array
(
    [product-link] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://...linkhere
            [1] => https://wwwle.com/banana
        )

    [product-img-src] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://image-goes-here.jpg
            [1] => https://www.example.com/kittykat.jpg
        )

    [h3-title-text] => Array
        (
            [0] => The title goes here
            [1] => Oh look, another title!
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => â¬20,00
            [1] => â¬540,00
        )

)
```

Comment: Why not leave the data in those very handy arrays. What exectly are you trying to do with this data that makes you think it all needs to be in scalar variables

Comment: I need to use them to build a div for each group. Like this: `<div id="master">
<h3>[h3-title-text][0] => The title goes here</h3>
<a href="[product-link][0] => https://...linkhere" target="_blank">
<img src="[product-img-src][0] => https://image-goes-here.jpg">
<span>[price][0] => €20,00</span>
</a>
</div>`

Comment: So get the data out of the array directly, loop over one array and then get the relevant occurance from each of the other arrays

Comment: Thats basically what you just showed us in your last comment

Comment: How can I echo the `[h3-title-text] var » [0]` in my `PHP` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arrays like this, in a foreach loop and utilise the `$idx` to address the correct item from all the other arrays

```
//The array you say you have produced!
$res= [
        'product-link'      => ['https://...linkhere', 'https://wwwle.com/banana'],
        'product-img-src'   => ['https://image-goes-here.jpg', 'https://www.example.com/kittykat.jpg'],
        'h3-title-text'     => ['The title goes here', 'Oh look, another title!'],
        'price'             => ['20,00','540,00']
];
```

So to process those arrays I did

```
foreach ( $res['product-link'] as $idx => $prod ) :
?>
        <div id="master"> 
            <h3><?php echo $res['h3-title-text'][$idx]; ?></h3> 
            <a href="<?php echo $prod; ?>" target="_blank"> 
                <img src="<?php echo $res['product-img-src'][$idx] ?>"> 
                <span><?php echo $res['price'][$idx]; ?></span> 
            </a> 
        </div>
<?php
endforeach;
```

RESULT

```
        <div id="master"> 
            <h3>The title goes here</h3> 
            <a href="https://...linkhere" target="_blank"> 
                <img src="https://image-goes-here.jpg"> 
                <span>20,00</span> 
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div id="master"> 
            <h3>Oh look, another title!</h3> 
            <a href="https://wwwle.com/banana" target="_blank"> 
                <img src="https://www.example.com/kittykat.jpg"> 
                <span>540,00</span> 
            </a> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working...

Comment: Not working yet... Should I use this code after this? `printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res,true));`

Comment: the array looks like this: `Array
(
    [product-link] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://...linkhere
            [1] => https://www.example.com/banana
        )

    [product-img-src] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://image-goes-here.jpg
            [1] => https://www.example.com/kittykat.jpg
        )

    [h3-title-text] => Array
        (
            [0] => The title goes here
            [1] => Oh look, another title!
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => â¬20,00
            [1] => â¬540,00
        )

)`

Comment: I want to show the `div's` after this (in the code above) `printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res,true));`. Another thing: Why my array looks so diferente from yours (the one you have build)?

Comment: They only look different to the untrained eye, they are the same